# comment is not saved in view.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

The codes (below) must enable a user to comment on a post/page. Thus, the comment is linked to that page. But after the submit event, the comment is not saved, hence nothing is displayed except the comments from the Admin page.

**Function that display the page and the comment in *view.py***

```
def list_page(request, list_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        list_auction = Auction_listings.objects.get(id=list_id)
        categories = Category.objects.get(id = list_id)
        return render(request, "auctions/auc_details.html", {
            "detail": list_auction,
            "cats":categories,
            "user": request.user,
            "comments": list_auction.comment.all(),
        })
    else:
        list_auction = Auction_listings.objects.get(id =list_id)
        return render(request, "auctions/auc_details.html", {
            "detail":list_auction
        })
```

**comment function in view.py**

```
def comment(request, list_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        list_auction = get_object_or_404(Auction_listings, pk=list_id)
        if request.method == "POST":
            comment_form = forms.Create_comment(request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                com_t = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                com_t.comment = list_auction
                com_t.comment_by = request.user
                com_t.save()
                print(com_t)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("list_page", args=(list_auction.id,)))
                
        return render (request,"auctions/auc_details.html", {
            "detail": list_auction,
            "user": request.user,
            "comments": list_auction.comment.all(),
        })
```

**Route in *urls.py***

```
path("<int:list_id>/comment", views.comment, name="comment"),
```

**Form class in *form.py***

```
class Create_comment(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Comment
        fields = ['comment']
```

**Model class in *models.py***
*Comment model*

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="commentor", blank=False)
    comment_on = models.ForeignKey( Auction_listings, related_name="comment", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    comment_date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.comment}"
```

*Page model (auction_listings*

```
class Auction_listings(models.Model):
    auc_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    auc_details = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    auc_price = models.IntegerField()
    auc_date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    auc_created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creator", blank=True)
    auc_image = models.ImageField(default='rose.jpg', blank=True)
    auctions = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank= True, related_name="category")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.auc_title}"
```

**html page**

```
<form action="{% url 'comment' detail.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="hidden" name="auction_id" value="{{detail.id}}">
    <button type=" submit ">Create</button>
</form>
```

I tried to change the route to look like:

```
path("/comment/<int:list_id>", views.comment, name="comment"),
```

**Tried**
But that didn't change anything.

Comment: where are you setting the mandatory `comment_on` field?

Comment: `not saved?` or `not shown?` is it saved in your database?

Comment: @PersianMan It is not shown  because no comment was saved at the first place.

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide because a comment has to be on a particular page/post, and that make their relation to be OneToMany relation.

Comment: @Mohamed `print(com_t.id)`

Comment: @PersianMan that line has no effect on the overall code

Comment: @Mohamed check your first snippet, you're never setting "comment_on" you're setting "comment"

Comment: @Mohamed probably , the `com_t.save()` line raise an exception , wrap it with try/except and print the exception, probably the exception silenced in somewhere

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the comment to attach to list_auction there should be a connection between them

```
com_t.comment_on = list_auction
```

OR

```
com_t.comment_on_id = list_auction.id
```

in your case:

```
if comment_form.is_valid():
    com_t = comment_form.save(commit=False)
    com_t.comment = 'the text of comment'
    com_t.comment_on = list_auction
    com_t.comment_by = request.user
    com_t.save()
    print(com_t)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("list_page", args=(list_auction.id,)))
```

**NOTE: For better debugging, check your database to see how the data is stored**

Comment: I found the main error to be in the template page, however, another error is popping up.

Comment: @Mohamed Always check the path of data movement in the software, is the data from the form to the view complete? Are the data coming from View to ORM complete?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Call the *Create_comment from form.py*

```
def list_page(request, list_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        list_auction = Auction_listings.objects.get(id=list_id)
        categories = Category.objects.get(id = list_id)
        comment_form = forms.Create_comment()
        return render(request, "auctions/auc_details.html", {
            "detail": list_auction,
            "cats":categories,
            "user": request.user,
            "comments": list_auction.comment.all(),
            "com_form":comment_form,
        })
    else:
        list_auction = Auction_listings.objects.get(id =list_id)
        return render(request, "auctions/auc_details.html", {
            "detail":list_auction
        })
```

**2** Call the *""com_form""* on the template.

```
<form action="{% url 'comment' detail.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
   {{com_form}}
    <button type=" submit ">Create</button>
</form>
```